# How to use Laurent expansion of a function into this form?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How can I compute the Laurent expansion of the function
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(2z+1)(z-2)}$$
when $\frac{1}{2}<|z|<2$
with this $\frac{1}{z^2}$ term?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,I just dont konw how to solve this problem

Comment: Why did you add the two (contradictory) specifications "at $z=0$ when $\frac{1}{2}<|z|<2$" to the question of your exercise? What is the complete text of this exercise?

Comment: @AnneBauval good point actually, I completely overlooked 1/2<|z|<2 in my answer

Comment: sorry,it means exopand the formula at 0 point and the specifications is $\frac{1}{2}<|z|<2$,and the exercise is japanese

Comment: sorry,it means around 0,this is translation:For 1/2< |z| < 2, the Laurent expansion of this around z = 0 gives

Comment: I think it means use Taylor series,and rake the reciprocal of z,it's Taylor series will be a part of Laurent series.

Comment: And than you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So this is very simple;

first you compute the partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{\left(2x+1\right)\left(x-2\right)} = \frac{A}{2x+1}+\frac{B}{x-2}$$

which gives you A = -2/5 and B=1/5

so:

$$\frac{1}{\left(2x+1\right)\left(x-2\right)}=-\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2x+1}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{x-2}$$

and then you put those into the geometric series:

$$-\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2x+1}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{x-2}=-\frac{2}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-2x\right)^{n}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{2}{5}\cdot\left(-2\right)^{n}-\frac{1}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\right)x^{n}$$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the solution:
$$\begin{align}\frac1{\left(2z+1\right)\left(z-2\right)}
&=-\frac25\cdot\frac1{2z+1}+\frac15\cdot\frac1{z-2}
\\&=-\frac1{5z}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac1{2z}}-\frac1{10}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac z2}\\
&=-\frac1{5z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{2z}\right)^n-\frac1{10}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac z2\right)^j\\&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^j}{5\cdot2^{j-1}}\frac1{z^j}\right)-\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{10\cdot2^j}z^j\right)\end{align}$$
[Visual Complex Analysis-Annular Laurent Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F7kR.png)

Comment: sorry,I have edit the question

Comment: Sorry,this low quality question is asked by myself, and I edited the question.And Thans for your suggestion!

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not notice that you are the person who aked the question.